# Navigate through pictures in a compressed file without extracting

Tags: software-recommendation, archive, image-viewers

Is there a way to view and browse through pictures that are inside a compressed file (suppose .rar) without having to extract all of them?

When I open a certain rar file that contains pictures, if I double click any picture, Image Viewer opens it normally, but I am not able to navigate (with the arrows) to the next picture. I have to close the open one, and open the next one again. Is there any software able to do this?

Answer (score 3):

OK, mounting the ZIP or RAR or Tar file with Archive Mounter seems to be it! But there is a problem: if the file is password protected, Archive Mounter crashes. Submitting the bug right now.